# PHP Optional Params

Tags: php, performance, oop

I have the following PHP functions:

```
public function foo($a, $b, $c){

    q = xyz($a,$b,$c);
    return q;
}


public function foo($a, $b ){

    q = xyz($a,$b);
    return q;


}
```

I want to create a private function that evaluates if param `$c` is there it uses it, if its not; it does not.

So that what I eventually will do is call the private function to evaluate the params and then run query.

Comment: Why do you want to create a new function for that purpose? Just use `if(isset($c))`?

Comment: Your code isn't valid - and, besides, just define `function xyz ($a, $b, $c=null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to know exactly what you want because there is not a lot of a context in your question, but this seems straightforward enough to me - public method `foo()` accepts either 2 or 3 values, and then calls private method `xyz()`, which also accepts 2 or 3 values.

In this case you can make the third argument `$c` optional in each method by assigning a default value (`null` in the example below, but you can define a `string`, `int`, `array` etc. Whatever suits your scenario).

Presumably you are applying some functionality to the values passed into `foo()` before calling `xyz()` because otherwise I cannot see any reason for implementing that method.

Finally, you can implement code checking and using the value of `$c` in `xyz()`.

An example in the context of a class called `Bar` below:

```
class Bar
{
    public function foo($a, $b, $c = null)
    {
        // do something here, e.g: input validation
        // before calling private method Foo::xyz()
        return $this->xyz($a, $b, $c);
    }

    private function xyz($a, $b, $c = null)
    {
        // handle variables... isset($c) etc.
        // implement functionality
        return '';
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT** I see Alma Do suggested same in the question comments.

**EDIT** Actually in this case it's worth pointing out the default value for `$c` in the method signature for `xyz($a, $b, $c = null)` is redundant, since it will always have some value when called through `foo()` (either an explicit value or `null`). However, if you are calling `xyz()` internally on other parts of the method, with 2 or 3 values explicitly in different cases... you may very well want to do this so it's worth keeping the default value for flexibility.

The ultimate goal being, let `xyz()` itself decide if it wants to use the value of `$c` or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a default value in the function definition.
With that, the function can be called with or without that parameter and you can ask for the default to distinguish between the cases.
Choose a default that is least likely to be actually chosen as a value for the parameter.

```
<?php
    public function foo($a, $b, $c = null){

      if(is_null($c) {
        $q = doThis($a,$b);
      }
      else {
        $q = doThat($a,$b,$c);
      }
      return $q;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

look this,may be help you !

```
public function foo(){
    return call_user_func_array("xyz",func_get_args());
}
```

Comment: In object context this should be something like: `call_user_func_array(array($this, 'xyz'), func_get_args());`.

Comment: @Darragh   Yes,you are right, I forget it ,thank you!